# General issues translating from matlab to python/numpy/

Tags: python, numpy, matlab

I am trying to 'translate' a working matlab script to python using numpy.

In the matlab code some kind of variable is generated as follows:

```
GA.Ng=2;       % number of genes
GA.Np=Np;      % size of population
GA.NG=NG;      % number of generations
GA.pc=0.5;     % probability of crossover
GA.alpha=0.5;  % blend ratio for crossover
GA.pm=0.1;     % probability of a gene being mutated
GA.xmn=[0 0];  % vector of minimum values for unnormalized genes
GA.xmx=[5 5];  % vector of maximum values for unnormalized genes
```

How do I achieve this in python? I tried this but had no success:

```
def example1p6A(NG, Np, rf, pf):
    GA = np.zeros(1, dtype = [('Ng', int),
                              ('Np', int),
                              ('NG', int),
                              ('pc', int),                              
                              ('alpha', float),
                              ('pm', int),
                              ('xmin', float),
                              ('xmax', float)])

    GA['Ng'] = 2                    # Number of genes
    GA['Np'] = Np                   # size of population
    GA['NG'] = NG                   # number of generations
    GA['pc'] = 0.5                  # probability of crossover
    GA['alpha'] = 0.5               # blend ratio for crossover
    GA['pm'] = 0.1                  # probability of a gene being mutated
    GA['xmin'] = np.array([0, 0])   # vector of minimum values for unnormalised genes
    GA['xmax'] = np.array([5, 5])   # vector of maximum values for unnormalised genes

    # Init population:
    P = np.random.rand(5,5)

    #return (GA['Ng'][0], Np, rf, pf)
    return P
```

I get the error message

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, you could work with a [*dictionary*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html?highlight=dict#2to3fixer-dict):

```
def example1p6A(NG, Np, rf, pf):
    GA = dict(Ng=2,
              Np=Np,
              NG=NG,
              pc=0.5,
              alpha=0.5,
              pm=0.1,
              xmn=[0, 0],
              xmx=[5, 5])

    P = np.random.rand(5,5)

    return (GA['Ng'][0], Np, rf, pf)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you defined `xmin` and `xmax` as `float`, but you are trying to assign them as an array. So that's why you are getting the error. You are trying to assign an "input array from shape (2)" to something with "shape (1)". So, the solution is to define `xmin` and `xmax` as an array of `float`. Here's an example that should make it work.

```
def example1p6A(NG, Np, rf, pf):
    GA = np.zeros(1, dtype = [('Ng', int),
                              ('Np', int),
                              ('NG', int),
                              ('pc', int),                              
                              ('alpha', float),
                              ('pm', int),
                              ('xmin', (float, (2,))),
                              ('xmax', (float, (2,)))])

    GA['Ng'] = 2                    # Number of genes
    GA['Np'] = Np                   # size of population
    GA['NG'] = NG                   # number of generations
    GA['pc'] = 0.5                  # probability of crossover
    GA['alpha'] = 0.5               # blend ratio for crossover
    GA['pm'] = 0.1                  # probability of a gene being mutated
    GA['xmin'] = np.array([0, 0])   # vector of minimum values for unnormalised genes
    GA['xmax'] = np.array([5, 5])   # vector of maximum values for unnormalised genes

    # Init population:
    P = np.random.rand(5,5)

    #return (GA['Ng'][0], Np, rf, pf)
    return P
```

For more information on this, check out this link:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html